# Which nodejs logger with runtime log level change, plain text/JSON support and simple API

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I'm looking for nodejs logging library that allows:

- simple logging - I'd like to be able to call `log.debug('Something happened', objDump)` or `log.error('Got error', err)` and get `objDump` printed and `err` included in logs (as JSON or with stack trace in case of `Error`) - pretty much what [Bristol](https://github.com/TomFrost/Bristol) does. I need dead-simple API for logging, to avoid mess around with `util.format` magic and thinking of whether I should use `%j` or any other etc.
- log level change in runtime (I get an error and would like to switch logger to `debug` mode **without** restarting the app itself
- logging in both plain-text for humans and JSON for log collectors
- adding predefined metadata to every log statement (e.g. host name, application name, transaction ID etc)

I tried classics - Winston and Bunyan and while they had tons of features they lacked some of the above too.

E.g. Winston can add metadata via rewriters, but when logging error via `logger.error('Got error, err)` the error itself is not logged at all.
Bunyan cannot (AFAIK) log in human readable format unless you use its extra CLI, which I don't really want.

I was also trying Bristol, which was promising but then it turned out it did not allow changing log level in runtime.

In turn Log4JS lacks in setting metadata for every log statement (AFAIK).

Could you please point me to any other lib, or ways of doing the stuff above in one of the mentioned libs? I'm sure there exists a library like that. I can't believe I'm the one that has that wants logging library to do these things.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late but may help some others. [Pino](https://getpino.io) may be what you look for (or maybe you have already discovered)

- simple logging

I guess it does what you need

- log level change in runtime

That was what I was looking for before encountering this question, too: https://github.com/pinojs/pino-arborsculpture

- logging in both plain-text for humans and JSON for log collectors

Prints in JSON format, and provides separate tool for human-readable printing: https://getpino.io/#/docs/pretty

- adding predefined metadata to every log statement

https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=bindings-object

And it claims it is the fastest: https://getpino.io/#/docs/benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

did you try debug ? Quite simple but does the job 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

Comment: I saw debug but it lacks too many features, I can't see using it as a real logger. Also it has this irritating printf-like formatting :( So thanks for posting, but `debug` is not a way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bunyan can log in human readable for without using the CLI. You can do it by creating a class object for that and referring to the object in the stream in the following manner:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
function MyRawStream() {}
MyRawStream.prototype.write = function (rec) {
    console.log(rec.time.toISOString(),
                bunyan.nameFromLevel[rec.level],
                rec.msg);
}
var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name:'play',
    streams: [
    {
        level: 'info',
        stream: new MyRawStream(),
        type: 'raw'
    }]
});
```

After creating this, you can use :

```
log.info('hi...');
```

To test... which then looks like

```
2017-03-07T05:49:56.890Z info hi...
```

You can also use colors within logging in the following way by just importing

```
var colors = require('colors/safe')
```

and changing the console.log option in the MyRawStream write method:

```
console.log(colors.red('[%s]')+' '+colors.blue('%s')+': '+colors.green('%s'),
            rec.time.toISOString(),
            bunyan.nameFromLevel[rec.level],
            rec.msg);
```

You can adjust everything accordingly by changing the write method